# Unable to undo rebase stream

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We were trying to rebase our stream.

After click on complete we got issue like some thing is corrupted. [Sorry my collegue did not take the screenshot of error]

we tried to redo the rebase operation.

It said unable to collect information about view

When we try undo rebase we got following error.

---

```
Rebase Stream
---------------------------
Error cancelling rebase of stream 'IELoc--Dev100'.

Integration activity change set is not empty.

---------------------------
OK 
---------------------------
```

How to complete or undo the rebase now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the process of cancelling, there is no going back: you must proceed all the way to completion of that "cancel" operation.

The technote "[Rebase fails with error: integration activity change set is not empty](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21179696)" can give some elements to resolve the situation.
The problem can occur when other *external* operations have been done during the rebase: a `cleartool rmver` (delete version), for instance, would be very dangerous.

The idea of a cancel (of a deliver or a rebase) is to **undo checkout** all the versions previously checked out in order to be merged.
You need to make sure all those versions can be checked out: sometimes a right issue can prevent the `unco`, sometimes, the version was already checked *in*.

Now, if the activity associated with the rebase is actually empty, there is an utilty called 'ucmutil' which can reset the rebase state, making it "vanish".
But that should be used with caution, and under the supervision of IBM Rational Support.
See "[Canceling UCM rebase fails with error: cleartool: Error: Rebase in progress on stream](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146614)" and "[About ucmutil](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237620)".